# How to Handle Empty HTTP JSON Responses in Python

Tags: python, http

I need to handle empty responses and break my loop when an empty responses occurs.

```
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=params)
data = response.json()


 print(data)


 if data == '[]': 
    # Break from loop here #
```

Normally, printing data variable returns something along the lines of

```
[{'application':'GMAIL'}]
```

When no data is returned, printing data variable results simply in:

```
[]
```

I've also tried `data == ""` and `data == None`, however the comparison never returns true.

Comment: You're asking `response.json()`, so you're always going to get a Python data structure; not the string `[]`. So you can check for `if data == []`, or even `if not data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check using `if` or `if not`. This works to check (amongst others) whether lists, dicts, tuples, strings are empty. It may be a bit counter-intuitive, as it seems you're asking whether the list itself exists, but not - you're asking whether (or not) it contains anything else than nothing.

**for example:**

```
data = response.json()
if not data:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You simple need to compare to a literal empty list instead of the string of one. In your current code, you are checking if the data is a string, but it seems that you want to check if your data is an empty list instead. Here's how your code could be instead:

```py
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=params)

    data = response.json()
    print(data)

    if data == []:
        # you can add any other code which you would like to call 
        # like something related to logging before the break if it makes sense in your application.
        break
```

You can of course format this however you like, or, as is mentioned in the code comment, add other code before you break the loop.